# How to remove a tag from favourite tags?

Tags: support

Suppose I added a tag 'xyz' to my favorite tags and now I want to remove it. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the <kbd>X</kbd> next to the tag.

[image]

This is in the sidebar:

[image]

Comment: From where did you get this view...I can't see it :(

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: ohhh...my 'stackoverflow' and 'unix.stackexchange' accounts are showing what you answered but 'superuser' was not showing favorite tags at all but now after refresh it is showing, thanks